# Magento 1.6 /admin always redirects to store after SUPEE-9767

Tags: admin, admin-panel, magento-1.6, supee-9767

I recently patched a 1.6 site with `SUPEE-9767`, on our development copy I encountered no issues, but after I pushed it onto the live host I could no longer get into the admin area.

**I would get the following redirects:**

```
/admin (302) -> /index.php/admin
/index.php/admin (302) -> /
```

I've flushed the cache, rebuilt the indexes, and confirmed that the file perms are correct but still the same behaviour.

It feels like I'm overlooking something.

Comment: try to access admin through yoursite.com/dowloader once in the dowloader at the top you will see an option to go back to Admin Panel. Click that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've literally just spent most of my afternoon debugging this issue.  The issue only occurs when https is enabled (which might explain why it doesn't occur in your dev environment).

Line 835 of `PATCH_SUPEE-9767_CE_1.6.2.0_v1-2017-05-25-09-32-57.sh` makes this change to `_checkBaseUrl` in `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php`:

```
-        $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB, Mage::app()->getStore()->isCurrentlySecure());
-
+        $baseUrl = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB,
+            Mage::getConfig()->shouldUrlBeSecure($request->getPathInfo())
+        );
```

The issue is that `shouldUrlBeSecure` returns false because the admin frontname is not on the list of secure URLs.  That causes `Mage::getBaseUrl` to return the unsecure base_url, and subsequent comparison with the current URL to fail (different protocol/scheme).  Therefore Magento will redirect you to the base_url (i.e. the redirect to the http home page behaviour you're seeing).

I hate core hacks as a fix, but undoing the effect of that patch at line 317 of `app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php` seems to be the best option.

Cue Ben Marks...
[image: Did you just edit the core?]

Comment: Note SUPEE-9767 for other versions of Magento 1.x don't include this change, so I'm puzzled as to why it's there for 1.6,

Answer (score 0):

Definitely not. Put it in
app\code\local\Mage\Core\Controller\Varien

I just tested and it worked like that